# UWP Compiles in debug mode, not release mode/.NET native tool chain ILT0005

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, uwp

I have a UWP project that relies on several packages (like Template 10, EF Core, NewtonSoft) and class libraries `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>`

When running in debug mode all works fine, when attempting to build in release mode or using the .NET native tool chain I get the following errors:

```
ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Source\Repos-2017-software\eVend\eVend\eTouchRetail\obj\x86\Debug\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\eTouchRetail.rsp"' returned exit code -1073740791
```

And also multiple errors like the below for different `Types` and `Methods`:

```
Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RefreshContainer' from assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.PullToRefreshListView'. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
```

I'm seeing a lot of warnings in the error window like the below for different namespaces:

```
The referenced component 'C:\Users\shaun\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.2\build\netstandard2.0\\ref\System.Linq.Expressions.dll' could not be found.
```

What's going on here? How do I go about diagnosing this?

Comment: It might possible that some library might not be compatible or using reflection which gets's excluded during compilation with .Net Native Tool chain. Consider adding ` <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />` in your default.rd.xml if that is not working for you have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference)